# Timing function with parameters over a range

Tags: python

```
loops = 25

a = range(1, loops)

def f(x):
    return 3 * log(x) + cos(x) ** 2
```

What's the best way to use the timeit for this?
I've tried several times, but constantly getting errors. I'd like to run `f` times equal to loops.

so far I've got `print(timeit.timeit(lambda: f(5)))`, and a half of dozen error filled tries with toying with parameters of the timeit constructor.

continuing further. I have another similar example.

```
a = np.arange(1, loops)

r = 3 * np.log(a) + np.cos(a) ** 2
#Using 2 instead of a
print(timeit.timeit("3 * np.log(2) + np.cos(2) ** 2", setup="import numpy as np"))
```

How can I incorporate the range `a` into the stmt string of timeit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Python >= 3.5

> The optional globals argument specifies a namespace in which to execute the code.
>
> Changed in version 3.5: The optional globals parameter was added.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.timeit

```
>>> import timeit
>>> a = range(1, 1000)
>>> timeit.timeit("sum(a)", globals=globals())
10.732978596999601
```

### Python < 3.5

Build your namespace in the setup statement (the old way).

> stmt and setup may also contain multiple statements separated by ; or newlines, as long as they don’t contain multi-line string literals.

```
In [2]: setup = """
   ...: a = range(1, 1000)
   ...: """

In [3]: timeit.timeit("sum(a)", setup=setup)
Out[3]: 10.133886003999578
```

This also seems to work just fine even though it contains a multi-line string literal...

```
In [11]: setup = """
a = '''heh
hoh
hih
'''
def f(x):
    #print(x)
    return len(x)
"""

In [12]: timeit.timeit("f(a)", setup)
Out[12]: 0.08516639499976009
```

Comment: Thanks alot, were not away that I could use the setup like so

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2, you could go with the following:

```
stmt = "results = list(map(f, a))"

stp = """
import math

def f(x):
    return 3 * math.log(x) + math.cos(x) ** 2

loops = 25
a = xrange(1, loops)
"""

# will apply f to each elmnt of a once
print(timeit.timeit(stmt=stmt, setup=stp, number=1))
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I incorporate the range `a` into the stmt string of timeit ?

Use string formatting:

```
loops = 25
setup = "import numpy as np"
statement = "3 * np.log(2) + np.cos(2) ** np.arange(1, %d)" % loops
timeit.timeit(statement, setup=setup)
```